# Can every hyperplane be described as $\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\Bbb F^n\mid a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n=0\}$ for some $a_1,...,a_n$ with $a_i\neq0$ for some $i$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655233/understanding-hyperplanes-as-a-set/3655279#comment7523424_3655279) that if $H = \{ (x_1, …, x_n) \in \mathbb{F}^n \mid a_1x_1 + … + a_n x_n = 0 \}$ for some $a_1, …, a_n$ with $a_i \neq 0$ for some $i$, then $H$ is a hyperplane. My question is about the converse:

> Can every hyperplane $H$ be described as $H = \{ (x_1, …, x_n) \in \mathbb{F}^n \mid a_1x_1 + … + a_n x_n = 0 \}$ for some $a_1, …, a_n$ with $a_i \neq 0$ for some $i$?

(My definition of hyperplane is a subspace whose dimension is 1 less than that of the ambient space.)

Here is my attempt:

Let $H$ be a hyperplane. Write $\mathbb{F}^n = H \oplus H^\perp$, and note that $H^\perp$ has dimension 1, so it is spanned by some nonzero vector $a$, i.e. $H^\perp = \text{span}(a)$. Take the orthogonal complement of both sides to get $H = (\text{span}(a))^\perp$. So we have $H = (\text{span}(a))^\perp = \{ a \}^\perp = \{ (x_1, …, x_n) \in \mathbb{F}^n \mid a_1x_1 + … + a_nx_n = 0 \}$. Since $a$ was nonzero, some $a_i$ is nonzero, as required.

Comment: How do you define $H^\perp$ without an inner product?

Comment: @amd Oh, I'm not sure. Let's suppose $\mathbb{F}^n$ is an inner product space with the usual inner product? Would that make things ok? Also, I'm curious to know whether the result still holds if we don't have an inner product?

Comment: One can make similar arguments using the dual space and annihilators of subspaces, so having an inner product isn’t strictly necessary (and the Riesz representation theorem connects them).

Comment: @amd Ok, I don't know much about that but it sounds interesting. I've only learned about inner product spaces where $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R} \text{ or } \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v_2,...,v_n$ span $H$. Choose $v_1 \notin H$, then the $v_k$ span the ambient space.

Define a linear functional by defining it on the basis: $f(v_1) = 1$ and $f(v_k) = 0$ for $k >1$.

Then $H = \{ x | f(x) = 0 \}$. Note that $f(v_1) = 1$ so $f \neq 0$.

We have
$f(x) = f(\sum_k x_k e_k) = \sum_k x_k f(e_k) $ and note that $a_k=f(e_k) \neq 0$ for at least one $k$ (otherwise this would contradict $f \neq 0$).

Then
$H= \{ x | \sum_k a_k x_k = 0 \}$ as required.

Comment: Very nice, so this looks like it doesn't reference any inner product and is more general than my attempt.

Comment: There is no problem defining an inner product on $\mathbb{F}^n$, it is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: Do you know if the equation defining a hyperplane is unique (up to nonzero scalar multiplication)?

Comment: It is unique in the context of a particular basis.

Answer (score 1):

An important observation is,$\mathbb{F}^n$ is equipped with the natural basis vectors $e_{k}$ where $e_{k}$ is the vector which is $1$ at the $k^{th}$ place and $0$ elsewhere.Now you have the collection of linear functionals $e_{k}^{*}$ where $e_{k}^{*}(e_{m})=\delta_{km}$,which form a basis for the dual of $\mathbb{F}^{n}$.Now notice that the hyperplane $H$ is the kernel of a linear functional $f$,which can be expressed uniquely in terms of these dual basis vectors as $f=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}e_{k}^{*}$.Being the kernel of $f$,$H$ is the set of all $(x_{1},x_{2},..,x_{n})$ such that $f(x_{1},x_{2},..,x_{n})=0$,which,when $f$ is expressed as above and $(x_{1},x_{2},..,x_{n})$ is expressed as a linear combination of the natural basis vectors in $\mathbb{F}^{n}$,gives what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, the idea that a hyperplane is the kernel of a linear functional is interesting. I didn't know that when I first read your answer but now I see why.